# Compare String with Pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Want to using C# Regex to match string. but always return false. code below

```
bool isMatch(string preDZ, string matchStr)
{

    string pat = preDZ + "/d{8}";
    Regex reg = new Regex(pat);

    return reg.Match(matchStr).Success;
}
```

Print(isMatch("AS", "AS00000001"));

but always return false. how to set the pattern to match the string "AS" + 8 length digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try something looks like this:

```
bool isMatch(string preDZ, string matchStr)
{
    string pat = preDZ + @"\d{8}";
    Regex reg = new Regex(pat);

    return reg.Match(matchStr).Success;
}
```

Comment: modify string pat = preDZ + "\\d{8}";, and it working now.

Comment: @KenChu I added `@` to string, so it more clearility than `"\\"`